# mod_rewrite not working?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a bunch of non-existent urls that need to be redirected to new ones, though they are not working... mod_rewrite does work and is enabled, I'm wondering if the redirect URL has to actually exist in order for a redirect ot work.

Here is what I have:

```
Redirect 301 /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?display=action&emptyoverride=yes&template=Assets/XHTML/Advantage.html http://domain.com/the-bag-to-nature-advantage.html
```

**UPDATE**
this is the request that comes in [indexed in google!]
http://domain.com//cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?display=action&emptyoverride=yes&template=Assets/XHTML/Advantage.html

this is where it needs to go:
http://domain.com/the-bag-to-nature-advantage.html

Comment: this is present in your htaccess file?

Comment: `Redirect` is a part of mod_alias, not mod_rewrite.  And I'm pretty sure it won't work on your query params..

Comment: Please could you explain precisely what you want to do (ie examples of what comes in and what should come out)?

Comment: @ShaneMadden True, but I'd add that Mod_Rewrite will work on the Query params.

Answer (score 1):

To use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^display=action&emptyoverride=yes&template=Assets/XHTML/Advantage\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/cgi-bin/commerce\.cgi$ http://domain.com/the-bag-to-nature-advantage.html [R=301]
```

Note that this is for if it's in your `VirtualHost` context; strip the leading slash on the `RewriteRule` if you put it in a `Directory` or `htaccess` context.